# Keycloak Authenticator SPI Example not working because of wrong relative path in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, authentication, keycloak

I followed the walkthrough for setting up a custom authenticator spi for keycloak.I'm trying to use the example code from https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/authenticator .
But when I run mvn clean install wildfly:deploy i'm getting this error :

```
FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.keycloak:keycloak-examples-parent:8.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.keycloak:keycloak-parent:pom:8.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.keycloak:keycloak-examples-parent:8.0.0-SNAPSHOT, C:\Users\dazoulay\Downloads\keycloak-master\keycloak-master\examples\pom.xml, line 20, column 13
```

What I did :

`mvn clean install`

on /keycloak-master folder OK

After that I tried to follow instruction found on Github Readme

So I tried

```
mvn clean install wildfly:deploy
```

on the /keycloak-master/examples/providers/authenticator but I got the "Non-resolvable parent Error"

I also Tried the git checkout 8.0.0 but I got the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

You need to start the build at the root of the of the project, not the subproject. So instead of

```
cd keycloak/examples/providers/authenticator
mvn clean install
```

do:

```
cd keycloak
mvn clean install
```

Second option, checkout a tag, then build from the subproject (this is likely the better option as it will go faster)

```
cd keycloak/examples/providers/authenticator
git checkout 8.0.0
mvn clean install
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, could you give me more information about the second option ?

Comment: If you run those commands above where you checkout the tag, you don't have to compile from the root because maven can download the required compile artifacts from maven central. When you're on a snapshot, it's hit or miss whether or not existing compiled artifacts exist or if they're the correct ones

Comment: Ok, edit your original question and paste _exactly_ what you did from start to finish and the entire output of the operation. Clearly we're missing some information :)

Comment: Edit Done ;), If you need more info don't hesitate to ask, and thank you again for your help

Comment: still need more info. Please include how you're obtaining the code, and paste the complete checkout log, and complete maven log. Just include everything